# Merge two similar XML Node in one Node in Java

Tags: java, xml, xmlnode

How can 2 similar XML nodes can be merged to form a single Node.
The requirement is say, I have a student node with id as 100 and I get an updated student node with same id. If this updated node have some additional properties, these should get added to resultant Node. Also if any of the property is updated that should also gets overridden in resultant Node. Below is an example.

Current Node :

```
<student id="100">
    <school>Saint Dnyaneshwar School</school>
    <division>science</division>
    <percentage>60.06</percentage>
</student>
```

New Node :

```
<student id="100">
    <address>Pune</address>
    <height>145cm</height>
    <percentage>70.05</percentage>
</student>
```

Resultant Node :

```
<student id="100">
    <school>Saint Dnyaneshwar School</school>
    <division>science<division>
    <percentage>70.05</percentage>
    <address>Pune</address>
    <height>145cm</height>
</student>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: How do you read those nodes? Are they in the same stream or file, or in different ones? Did you try anything? There are many ways to do this in Java: SAX, DOM, XPath, JDOM, DOM4J, XML Reader, XSLT Transform. If you have any code you used to read the files, post it since it could be a starting point for a possible answer.

Comment: I am using w3c Document apis to achieve this things. I have 2 xml files..source files only have the limited configuration to be merged in destination file. And destination file is well formatted file which seats on a server. I am trying put config snippet from source to destination using Java code.